# How to echo a div class?

Tags: php, class, html, echo

Not sure how to do this... I'm a bit of a php noob. I'm trying to echo the div class '.header1'

In my css I've given .header1 a background image and I want that to appear, but I'm not having any luck so my code must be wrong. Here it is:

```
echo '<div class="header1">';

.header1 {
background: url(_images/header1.png);
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried it with and without the closing div but neither have worked.

Comment: Is PHP enabled on your server?

Comment: You might need to post more code - like your CSS, and also where the div ends.

Comment: Yes. All my php is working fine, it's just this one that isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The div tag needs both an ending tag and **content**.

If there is no content, you need to define it's `height` and `width` manually.

Comment: I want just the css background image to be echoed. There is no content so how do I give it content when there is none?

Comment: give it a `height` and `width` via css.

Comment: That's worked! All I needed was the width and height in the css. It was so simple really. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother but for some reason the background image is only appearing in Safari and not the other browsers. Any idea why this could be? :S

Comment: @user1636968: Have you cleared the cache of the other browsers? Also, the styling in your example lacks a closing brace, is that also true of your actual code? If there is any HTML content following the PHP code then you must use the closing PHP tag '?>' after your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

A. You `echo` is working .. you are probably not seeing anything because its an HTML tag try

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="header1">Hello</div>';
?>
```

B. You should try and make sure you set PHP open tag `<?php` and close tag `?>` as demostrated above

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I echo html in php I like to use the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$div = <<<DIV
    <div class="header1"></div>
DIV;
```

Just looks *so* much better, to me, especially when your strings get more complex, i.e. quotes and stuff.